# How do i get the first name from the customer_name column

Tags: mysql

[image]

```
 select substring(custmer_name, 1, instr(custmer_name, ' ')) as first_name from sales.customers;
```

This solution is giving me the answer but It doesn't work with the last name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test this: I used locate function to define the position of ' '.

```
SELECT 
LEFT(customer_name, LOCATE(' ',customer_name)-1) as first_name,
RIGHT(customer_name, LENGTH(customer_name)-LOCATE(' ',customer_name)) as last_name
FROM customer;
```

Result set:
[image: Click to see image]

Answer (score 0):

Use **SUBSTRING_INDEX()** it takes 3 parameter:

1. Column name
2. Delimiter
3. Occurrence count

You can find more explanation in this [article](https://sebhastian.com/mysql-split-string/#:%7E:text=To%20split%20a%20string%20in,(expression%2C%20delimiter%2C%20count)%3B)

**Query**

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(customer_name,' ', 1) as first_name, 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(customer_name,' ', -1) as last_name FROM customer;
```